The development of $j$-invariant
I have always been interested in $j$-invariant. And by chance, I read the part titled Toward a History of Nineteenth-Century Invariant Theory in the book Ideas and their Reception Proceedings of the Symposium on the History of Modern Mathematics.
If you read page 164 of Toward a History of Nineteenth-Century Invariant Theory, you will find the following passage:

Finally, the application to (10) of the identification equations in (11) generated $$ u=\alpha\epsilon-4\beta\delta+3\gamma^2, \tag{12}$$ an invariant of the binary quartic. As innocent as this may seem, it represented a fundamental breakthrough in the theory of invariants, for Cayley's method of hyperdeterminants had begotten an invariant of the binary quartic different from the invariant $$\alpha\gamma\epsilon-\alpha\delta^2-\epsilon\beta^2-\gamma^3+2\beta\gamma\delta \tag{13}$$ generated by Boole's method. Furthermore, as Boole discovered shortly after receiving the latter from Cayley in which he detailed this new finding, the binary quartic had yet another invariant $$(\alpha\epsilon-4\beta\delta+3\gamma^2)^3-27(\alpha\gamma\epsilon-\alpha\delta^2-\epsilon\beta^2-\gamma^3+2\beta\gamma\delta)^2, \tag{14}$$ a polynomial function of the invariants in (12) and (13).28 Thus, new invariants arose as special combinations of known invariants, and while this observation came to determine the course of nineteenth-century invariant
theory, neither Cayley nor Boole anticipated such developments in 1845. For Cayley, especially, the most immediate concern was to generate simple invariants, and by 1846, he had devised a new method for doing just that.

After reading the paragraph above, I was able to see that mathematicians Cayley and Boole studied invariants through the formula $S^3-27T^2$, which we can conveniently call $S=\alpha\epsilon-4\beta\delta+3\gamma^2$ and $T=\alpha\gamma\epsilon-\alpha\delta^2-\epsilon\beta^2-\gamma^3+2\beta\gamma\delta$, respectively. However, if we read the article on Wikipedia, we can see that the $j$-invariant is defined as $j=1728\frac{S^3}{S^3-27T^2}$. This makes me curious.
As I read the book, I was convinced that the mathematicians Cayley and Boole created the invariant called $S^3-27T^2$, but I did not understand the circumstances under which the j-invariant suddenly appeared. Ultimately, I'm curious about which mathematician came up with the invariant $j=1728\frac{S^3}{S^3-27T^2}$, with what background and to what end.
And I read the book 'A history of abstract algebra by Israel Kleiner'. If you read page 115 in this book,

The notion of invariance is of course fundamental in mathematics (as it is in science).
Gauss was among the first to explicitly recognize invariance in his number-theoretic
investigations of binary quadratic forms, $f (x, y) = ax^2 +bxy +cy^2$. He showed that
the discriminant $D = b^2−4ac$ of the form f is invariant under a linear transformation
of its variables. More generally, if $f$ is transformed by a linear mapping $T$ of the
variables $x, y$ into the form $g(u, v) = ku^2 + luv + mv^2$, then any function $I$ of
the coefficients of $f$ which satisfies the relation $I (k, l, m) = t ^k I (a, b, c)$ is called an
invariant of $f$ under $T$ ($t$ denotes the determinant of the matrix of $T$ ). A corresponding
definition applies to a form (i.e., a homogeneous polynomial) of any degree in any
number of variables.
Invariants also proved important in geometry, especially projective and algebraic
geometry, which sought properties of figures invariant under projective and birational
transformations, respectively. These were the intrinsic properties of the respective
geometries.
Cayley was inspired to study invariants by an 1841 paper of Boole on the subject, entitled “Exposition of a general theory of linear transformations”.
Initially, his focus was on geometry. (Since a form $f$ of degree $m$ in $n$ variables is a
homogeneous polynomial, $f = 0$ represents a curve, a surface, ... .) Soon, however,
he adopted an abstract point of view and, when he was twenty-two, formulated the
first of two basic problems of invariant theory:


[To] find all the derivatives [invariants] of any number of functions [forms],
which have the property of preserving their form unaltered after any linear
transformation of the variables [3]. [The term “invariant” was coined by
Sylvester.]


In 1846 he devised a method for generating invariants of binary forms. For example, he
showed that $g = ae−4bd+3c^2$ is an invariant of the binary quartic form $ax^4+4bx^3y+
6cx^2y^2 + 4dxy^3 + ey^4$ under unimodular transformations (linear transformations of
determinant 1), where $a, b, c, d$ are complex numbers. Over a twenty-five-year period,
starting in 1854, Cayley wrote ten papers, all entitled “Memoir upon quantics [forms]”
(numbered consecutively), computing invariants of various forms

In the formula $I (k, l, m) = t ^k I (a, b, c)$, I thought to leave only $t^k$ on the right side and divide $I$, so mathematicians created $j$-invariant like now. I thought that this might have been born.
